# GRUB2 doesn't see Windows 8 Consumer Preview

Tags: grub, multi-boot, windows-8-preview

I installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview, and Windows replaced the boot manager (GRUB). Usually, I could restore GRUB using [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/), but in this case I had to use [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/), because SGD returned errors.

Now, I can run Ubuntu and Debian, but not Windows. GRUB doesn't seem to recognize the Windows installation as operating system. I tried `update-grub` and `os-prober`. How can I make Windows visible for GRUB?

Boot Info Script returns [this](http://pastebin.com/WX1ubwrb)

Comment: Your title says GRUB2, but your body and tags say GRUB. Are you using GRUB2 or GRUB?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a Windows entry like you would normally do.

Yes, this requires some fiddling. I guess you open up [a random example](http://boff.wordpress.com/2007/01/17/editing-bootgrubmenulst-to-change-the-grub-boot-menu/) and copy the Windows part of it into your own `menu.lst` usually located in `/boot` or `/boot/grub` or somewhere around there. Then the only thing left to do is finding the right root to boot from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have GRUB2. If that's so, you can't add Windows to a menu.lst anymore. It's slightly more complex. You'll need to create a script for the menu entry in /etc/grub.d/:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub.d/50_windows
```

Then you'll need to create a simple script that will allow you to boot from the appropriate partition. As far as the script itself, it should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat << EOF
menuentry "Windows 8 Consumer Preview" {
set root=(hd0,1)
chainloader (hd0,1)+1
}
EOF
```

But I'm not sure exactly, and it will of course depend on your boot setup, especially which drive/partition holds your Windows install. Remember that GRUB2 lists partitions starting with 1, not 0 like GRUB legacy did. That means hda1 will be `(hd0,1)` and NOT `(hd0,0)`. Next you need to mark it as executable so that grub can use it:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/50_windows
```

Then update GRUB so that it can find your new entry:

```
sudo update-grub
```

With any luck, you should now have a working Windows entry, but remember my example script will almost definitely not work for you, it will have to be modified for your install!

P. S. This tutorial may seem a little dumbed-down to the OP, who obviously seems to have decent technical knowledge. No disrespect; I was trying to be understandable to any noobs that may find this page later.

Comment: The OP is indeed using GRUB2, see the Pastebin link at the end of the question.